# Controller.doInit is not a function?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my application, we have a panel of back, next buttons that are included in every screen for navigation. From the next button, I want to call a Controller using:

```
 myApp.app.getController('folder.MyInfoController').submitMyInfoForm(nextButtonId);
```

However, I get a TypeError: controller.doInit is not a function. I have an init method in my controller which is already working.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error simply because *"folder.MyInfoController"* is **not** a controller - that is to say, it does not extend `Ext.app.Controller` which `Ext.app.Application::getController` is expecting to find.  Now for some bonus points...

My psychic senses are telling me that in all likelihood you are trying to find a view-controller - which is notably not the same as an application-controller.  They both share a base class but serve different purposes and ultimately have different implementations.  This is well defined in the API.

As a preface to the next paragraph, I'd also point out that what you are doing looks like an anti-pattern.  The biggest advantage of using the view-controllers is that they afford you all the conveniences of MVC whilst keeping your components decoupled from each another - there are only specific cases where you can justifying accessing one outside of the component scope and I can't think of any good reason why you'd need to access one from a global context.

That said, you can find a view-controller by obtaining a reference to the instantiated component (of type *"folder.MyInfo"* - or whatever you've called it) and [asking it for it's view-controller](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.AbstractComponent.html#method-getController).  Note that there is a **1:1** relationship between a component and it's view-controller - each instance of the former has a unique instance of the latter.

Comment: The documentation link is 404ing.